# Elements of a vector space are uniquely determined by the vectors of its direct sums?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help proving that if $V = U \oplus W$, then for every $v \in V$, there exist unique elements $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v=u+w$.

Comment: How do you define $\oplus$?

Comment: direct sum of vector spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u+w=u'+w'$ then $u-u'=w'-w\in U\cap W$ (because the left side of the equality is in $U$ and the right side is in $W$). From here we conclude $u-u'=0=w-w'\implies u=u'$ and $w=w'$ as desired.

This is because $U\cap W=\{0\}$ since the sum is direct.

Comment: OH RIGHT. IT'S SO GLARINGLY OBVIOUS I DIDN'T REALIZE IT. THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Sure, no problem. On the other hand at least one pair $u,w$ exists because by definition $U+W$ is the set $\{u+w|u\in U, w\in W\}$